# Simplifying Taylor Series for the function $\sqrt{2+x}$ about $x=3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have a past exam with the solution here. But I can't understand how they combined and simplified the terms going from the third last to the second last line. How did they get rid of $[1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5...(2n-3)]$? I'm not too familiar with the mathematics of factorials.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
(2n-3)!!&=\prod_{k=2}^n(2k-3)\\\\
&=(2n-3)(2n-5)\cdots (3)(1)\\\\
&=\frac{(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4)(2n-1)\cdots (4)(3)(2)(1)}{(2n-2)(2n-4)\cdots (4)(2)}\\\\
&=\frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the 2nd last line they've forgotten to include the $(-1)^{n+1}$ term inside the sum.

Perhaps the easiest way to show what's happening is by letting $n$ take some value. For arguments sake let's say $n = 7$, then the term you are confused about becomes

$$1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9 \cdot 11.$$

Now let's multiply both the top and bottom of this by $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot 10 \cdot 12 $ which produces

$$ \frac{ 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10 \cdot 11 \cdot 12 }{ 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot 10 \cdot 12 }. $$

Now if we generalise this expression by considering it for general $n$ rather than for the specific case of $n = 7$, we see it has the required form

$$ \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-2)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n-2)} .$$